# Android, не применяется атрибут "background" у кнопки

Tags: android, android-style

Имею две Activity: `Activity1` и `Activity2`, обе наследницы `AbstractActivity`.

В `AbstractActivity` есть функция, вызывающая popup с кнопкой:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_error_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_default"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_default" />
```

Атрибут `textcolor` работает в обеих Activity. Но. В `Activity1` у кнопки серый **фон**, а в `Activity2` - чёрный.

Если добавить атрибут, например,

`android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"`

То аналогично, фон первой кнопки изменится и станет синим, фон второй кнопки останется чёрным. Вопрос: почему так происходит и как установить фон второй кнопки?

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cuprum_regular</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**UPD1:**

Разбираясь, пришёл к такому промежуточному выводу:фон второй кнопки, это `colorAccent` из `AppTheme`. Поменяв его, поменялся и фон второй кнопки. Только это явно не решение, менять один из базовых цветов темы ради кнопки.

Понятно, что тут нужен стиль. Пытался сделать так:

```
<style name="buttonErrorPopupStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    </style>
```

Применив это к кнопке, эффект получил аналогичный: цвет текста меняется, цвет фона - нет.

Иннтуитивно я понимаю, что мой атрибут просто "не находят" и за неимением ставят вместо него атрибут темы. Но почему так происходит и как это решить не понятно всё ещё.

**UPD2**

Разобрался, почему у кнопок был разный фон в разных `Activity`. Почему - то в манифесте первой `Activity` стояла тема со своими атрибутами.

Актуальный вопрос - почему не работает `android:background`

Comment: В манифест у них используется одна и та же тема?

Comment: Да. Там вообще тем нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил сам заменой `Button` на `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно заменить `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"` в теме `AppTheme` на `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cuprum_regular</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```